# compare with one of the 5 options

Tags: regex, awk, sed, grep

I am trying to find words where second or third character is one of "aeiou".

```
# cat t.txt
test
platform
axis
welcome
option
```

I tried this but the word "platform" and "axis" is missing in the output.

```
# awk 'substr($0,2,1) == "e" {print $0}' t.txt
test
welcome
```

Comment: `awk '/^(..?[aeiou]).*/ {print $1}' t.txt`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use this awk solution that matches 1 or 2 of any char followed by one of the vowels:

```
awk '/^.{1,2}[aeiou]/' file

test
platform
axis
welcome
```

Or else use `substr` function to get a substring of 2nd and 3rd char and then compare with one of the vowels:

```bash
awk 'substr($0,2,2) ~ /[aeiou]/ ' file

test
platform
axis
welcome
```

---

As per comment below OP wants to get string without vowels in 2nd or 3rd position, Here is a solution for that:

```bash
awk '{
s=substr($0,2,2)
gsub(/[aeiou]+/, "", s)
print substr($0,1,1) s substr($0, 4)
}' file

tst
pltform
axs
wlcome
option
```

PS: This `sed` would be shorter for replacement:

```bash
sed -E 's/^(.[^aeiou]{0,1})[aeiou]{1,2}/\1/' file
```

Comment: Is it possible to remove those characters and get only tst, pltform, axs and wlcome?

Comment: Yes that is also possible, check my updated answer.

Comment: If I am not asking for too much, is it possible to extract the matching character? test e, platform a, axis i, welcome e ?

Comment: @shantanuo : so what exactly is ur actual requirement ? you're constantly moving the goal posts for anubhava

Comment: @shantanuo: It is always better to state all the requirements in question itself. Anyway for your last comment use: `sed -nE 's/^.[^aeiou]{0,1}([aeiou]{1,2}).*/\1/p' file`

Comment: @shantanuo [chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) are strongly discouraged on this forum. Ask 1 question and if you have a followup then ask a new question, don't add it in comments where others with similar questions in future aren't likely to find it or the answer.

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples only, please try following `awk` code. Written and tested in GNU `awk`, should work in any `awk`. Simple explanation would be, setting field separator as NULL and checking if 2nd OR 3rd field(character in current line basically) is any of `a e i o u` then print that line.

```
awk -v FS="" '$2~/^[aeiou]$/ || $3~/^[aeiou]$/'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/\<..\?[aeiou]/I!d' file
```

If the second or third character from the start of a word boundary is either a,e,i,o or u (of any case) don't delete the line.

Answer (score 1):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
test
platform
axis
welcome
option
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FPAT="."}index("aeiou", $2)||index("aeiou", $3)' file.txt
```

gives output

```
test
platform
axis
welcome
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` that field is any single character (`.`) using `FPAT`, then I filter lines using [`index`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) function, if 2nd field that is 2nd character is anywhere inside `aeiou` then `index` returns value greater than zero which is treated as true in boolean context and apply same function for 3rd field that is 3rd character and then apply logical OR (`||`) to their effects.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*